# crop video like we have cropped images using a grid in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am capturing video from my app and I need to crop that captured video just like we crop images. is there any way to do this?. I need to crop video after capturing it from camera. any one have any idea??

**is any third party api available?**

Comment: Yes. There is an awesome third party is available.     https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: @RajAggrawal i reviewed link u given but it is for filter video not for croping video like we done in images.

Comment: As per library documentation you can apply filters to the images as well as videos. You need to do some R&D on that. GPUImage is not straight froward implementable Lib but it is cool and Awesome. I have used many of the filters using this lib.I also used GPUImage in my large scale application for major feature.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GPUImageCropFilter to crop the video and image with the same filter. you need to integrate GPUImage library to access the filter.[GPUImage libarary](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)